# Mysql only get newest record where columns are set and get the empty columns from the next row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL database table with many columns that can be empty (null).
I would like in one result row the newest value for every column for one machine. So, if null, the value will be of one older row, like illustrated below.

Table content:

```
id name motorSpeed motorDelay F1type F2type F3type
1  001  200        null       1      null   null
2  002  400        0          0      0      0
3  001  null       50         0      1      1
```

Desired result:

```
id name motorSpeed motorDelay F1type F2type F3type
3  001  200        50         0      1      1
```

What would be the best query to get this aggregated result?

Comment: Why is motorSpeed in expected result 200 and not 400?

Comment: Because 200 is the latest value for machine '001'. 400 belongs to machine '002'

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `name` is the key and it can not be null. Also that you want to get the 'latest' values for name=001.

```
SELECT a.id, b.name, c.motorSpeed, d.motorDelay, e.F1type, f.F2type, g.F3type
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) b ON b.name=a.name
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE motorSpeed IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) c ON c.name=a.name
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE motorDelay IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) d ON d.name=a.name
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE F1type IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) e ON e.name=a.name
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE F2type IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) f ON f.name=a.name
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE F3type IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) g ON g.name=a.name
WHERE a.name='001';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,
       NAME,
       CASE WHEN MOTORSPEED IS NULL
            THEN MIN(MOTORSPEED)
            ELSE MOTORSPEED
        END AS MOTORSPEED,
       CASE WHEN MOTORDELAY IS NULL
            THEN MAX(MOTORDELAY)
            ELSE MOTORDELAY
        END AS MOTORDELAY,
       CASE WHEN F1TYPE IS NULL
            THEN MAX(F1TYPE)
            ELSE F1TYPE
        END AS F1TYPE,  
       CASE WHEN F2TYPE IS NULL
            THEN MAX(F2TYPE)
            ELSE F2TYPE
        END AS F2TYPE,
       CASE WHEN F3TYPE IS NULL
            THEN MAX(F3TYPE)
            ELSE F3TYPE
        END AS F3TYPE
FROM YOURTABLE;
```